# How to suppress 7zip verbose output but extraction status in percentage?

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, subprocess, 7zip

A sample output of 7zip extraction looks like this:

```
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 9770776 bytes (9542 KiB)

Extracting archive: tools\StrawberryPerl.7.exe
--
Path = tools\StrawberryPerl.7.exe
Type = 7z
Offset = 162816
Physical Size = 9607960
Headers Size = 11687
Method = LZMA:24m BCJ2
Solid = +
Blocks = 2

 78% 602 - perl\lib\auto\Module\Pluggable\.packlistProcess SpawnPoolWorker-6:
```

My question is, how can this be suppressed to get only the extraction percentage (`78% 602 - perl\lib\auto\Module\Pluggable\.packlistProcess SpawnPoolWorker-6:`)?

I found several answers on suppressing the verbose output, like:

1. Adding `>NUL:` to the end of the bat command, which will completely suppress the messages.
2. Using `subprocess.Popen` in Python with `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE`, which again suppressed all the messages.
3. Using `findstr /b /r /c:"\<Everything is Ok"` in bat command, which will filter out based on the  given string. Here I tried using regex somewhat like `\d+\%`, but didn't really help. As you see, I am not good at batch script. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try piping the output using:

```
[7z command] | findstr /rc:"[0-9][%]"
```